# ngFor not update view unless click on view Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, view, click, ngfor

I tried detectChanges(), marforCheck() as well, reassign but nothing changes. They just change after I click on view again.
Scenario:
I get data from store, I tracked data change successfully in subscribe function.

```
    this.allInfo$.subscribe(data => {
      this.allInfos = data;
    });
```

```
 <div (click)="addInfo(social)" *ngFor="let info of allInfos"
         [ngClass]="{'active': info.connected}">
        <span>{{info.name}} {{info.connected}}</span>
      </div>
```

When I click addInfo, app will open thirdparty dialog like firebase login, if success will return new data and update to allInfo$ I tracked. But the view does not changes? Is that angular  bug? View change if I click somewhere on screen
My angular version 7

UPDATED: My problem was resolved by using _ngZone.run()

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: @varman: no errors. If I click on view it will update. I think the issue because Angular didn't detect changes if open new popup from firebase auth.

Comment: Can you update the scenario of code that how you implemented? There is no angular bug, there may be implementation fault.

Comment: @varman: I add   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
after setdata, insert 2 lines: this.cdr.markforcheck(), this.cdr.detectChanges(), still not. I try another: this.allInfos = []; this.allInfos = data, still not. But I just click somewhere, view will update

Comment: a subscription **not** put a "listener" in the dbs, so any change in the dbs is reflex. Each change in the dbs, you need or get the list again or add manually to your array allInfos

Comment: @Eliseo: How can I add manually? I tried reassign, cloneDeep, splice, push,.. but nothing works. I want to update a boolean property of item in array. Many cases were done before until I face it with 3rd-party popup like firebase auth service. That mean when I click, a new windown open, it cancels detection change of Angular I think so.

Answer (score 0):

You kept the click event on the , so when you are clicking on that div it is updating.

```
<div  *ngFor="let info of allInfos"
         [ngClass]="{'active': info.connected}">
        <span (click)="addInfo(social)">{{info.name}} {{info.connected}}</span>
</div>
```

in this code the view will update when you click on the span

Comment: it didn't change. I think the issue because Angular didn't detect changes if open new popup from firebase auth.

Comment: There are multiple life chycle hook and ChangeDetection also in angular. I feel, the way he implemented doesn't work as normal

Comment: @varman: I used change detection successfully many times before. I think Angular cannot detect if a new window open like firebase authentication service. If I add a button without any click, I just click it and the view updated successfully. 
My demo work fine if there is no firebase service popup: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-fpwetj?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

## trackBy

```
   <div (click)="addInfo(social)" *ngFor="let info of allInfos;trackBy:trackByFunction"
             [ngClass]="{'active': info.connected}">
            <span>{{info.name}} {{info.connected}}</span>
    </div>
```

## .ts

```
trackByFunction(index, info){
if(!info)return null;
return info.id; //or return index;
}
```

Link:-https://medium.com/better-programming/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Comment: I tried but not successful, only click trigger re-render again. May be because third party open popup cancel detection changes of Angular.

Comment: For fresh data, you need to subscribe data and do ajax call each time and when you get fresh data...it will render on html. write as observable and subscribe it in constructor

Answer (score 0):

a subscription **not** put a "listener" in the dbs, so any change in the dbs is reflex. Each change in the dbs, you need or get the list again or add manually to your array allInfos.

You say "When I click addInfo, app will open thirdparty dialog like firebase login, if success will return new data and update to allInfo$"

I have no idea about your addInfo, so I supouse your addInfo is like

```
addInfo(data)
{
    this.service.addData(data).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res) //generally success
    })
}
```

You can so some like

```
addInfo(data)
{
    this.service.addData(data).subscribe(res=>{
       if (sucess)
         this.allInfos.push(data)
    })
}
```

or 
    addInfo(data)
    {
        this.service.addData(data).pipe(
          switchMap(res=>{
            return res.success?this.allInfo$:of(null)
          })
        ).subscribe(res=>{
           if (res)
             this.allInfos=res
        })
    }

It's possible that the "thirdparty dialog make a next to your $allInfo", (than all of this it's unnecesary) but I don't know. Imagine that you has a typical CRUD service like

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  endpoint: string = '[YOUR_DB_SERVER_IP]';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  // CREATE
  createProduct(productToCreate: IProduct): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.endpoint}/products`, productToCreate);
  }

  // READ
  readProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/products`);
  }

  // UPDATE
  updateProduct(objToUpdate: IProduct): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.endpoint}/products/${objToUpdate.id}`, objToUpdate};
  }

  // DELETE 
  deleteProduct(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.endpoint}/products/${objToDelete.id}`);
  }
}
```

We are changing so, each change emit an event

```
  private dbsChangeSubject = new Subject<any>();
  dbsChange = this.dbsChangeSubject .asObservable();

  // CREATE
  createProduct(productToCreate: IProduct): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.endpoint}/products`, productToCreate).pipe(
        tap(result=>{
          if (result.success)
             this.dbsChangeSubject.next(true)
        }))
    );
  }

  // UPDATE
  updateProduct(objToUpdate: IProduct): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.endpoint}/products/${objToUpdate.id}`, objToUpdate.pipe(
        tap(result=>{
          if (result.success)
             this.dbsChangeSubject.next(true)
        }))
    );;
  }

  // DELETE 
  deleteProduct(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.endpoint}/products/${objToDelete.id}`).pipe(
        tap(result=>{
          if (result.success)
             this.dbsChangeSubject.next(true)
        }))
    );
  }
}
```

Know we can subscribe to

```
this.service.dbsChange().pipe(
startWith(true),
switchMap(()=>{
    this.service.readProducts()
})).subscribe(res=>{
   this.products=res
})
```

Here we subscribe to "dbsChange", not to readProducts(), so we are listen to all the this.dbsChangeSubject.next that we has

Comment: Yes my addInfo is nearly similar to yours. But the difference here is it open a new window by AngularFireAuth service and return a promise. I update new data to Ngrx in that promise. Some people in Angular forums tell me use _NgZone.run

Answer (score 0):

As dlam said in his edited question, using `NgZone` in the new window solves the problem.

**Example:**

```
import { NgZone} from '@angular/core';

export class NewWindowComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.someService.getChangedData.subscribe(data => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.someData= data;
        });
    });
}
}
```